# how to get the values from the array elements in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of size 6 which contains a value in zeroth position as a string:

```
{"1111110"}
```

Now I want to read the contents of `array[0]` from last from 0 to 1.

How can I read the element ? and is there any inbuilt function in C#?

Answer (score 7):

```
var string0 = array[0];
foreach (char c in string0.Reverse()) {
  // do something with c
}
```

Comment: is ther any assembly reference to include to use .Reverse method since i am receiving a error in String0.Reverse

Comment: Make sure you are targeting .NET 3.5 or later and have `using System.Linq` at the top.

Comment: i am working in .NET 2.0 framework. so var isnt valid in this workspace. how can i do it in vs2005

Comment: @tech_guy - other examples will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.Reverse which takes char array

```
string reverString =new string(Array.Reverse( array[0].ToCharArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string value = array[0];
```

Now you can use: **[String.ToCharArray Method (Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c7h58e5.aspx)**

Eg.:

```
char[] arr;
arr = value.ToCharArray(0, 6);
```